# how to do speech recognition using python

Tags: python-3.x

i have tried

```
import speech_recognition as sr  

r = sr.Recognizer()                                                                                   
with sr.Microphone() as source:                                                                       
print("Speak:")                                                                                   
audio = r.listen(source)   

try:
    print("You said " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results; {0}".format(e))
```

but i didn't get the expected output it always shows could not understand the voice

Answer (score 0):

I would check out:
https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/

Should be just what you need :-D